# Save as new name each time

Tags: c#

I can save a screenshot on a timer, but how could I have it save as a new name and not overwrite every time?

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                           Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);

graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

bitmap.Save(@"c:tempscreenshot.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: may be you can try with append current datetime in name.

Comment: You don't need to do `bitmap as Image`. Just use `bitmap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to generate a unique name every time. There are several possibilities. One would be to add a datetime-string at the end:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 
              Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);

  graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

bitmap.Save(@"c:tempscreenshot" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: Thank you so so much I really appreciate it. You made my day. If I can do anything to repay you , just name it. Follow on twitter? itunes review? Thanks again

Comment: No problem, happy to help. If you're interested, this is my twitter handle : @Kennethtruyers

Answer (score 5):

You can use the handy method: `Path.GetRandomFileName()`

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 
              Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);

  graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

bitmap.Save("c://" + Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an integer (or some other numeric type) and increment it within your timer.  Then call your save method with something like:

```
bitmap.Save(string.Format("c:tempscreenshot.{0}.bmp", counter), ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

or use a GUID:

```
bitmap.Save(string.Format("c:tempscreenshot.{0}.bmp", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")), ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a new filename everytime based on the current time. Something like this:

```
string GenerateFilename() {
    string file = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy.MM.dd HH.mm.ss") + ".bmp";
    return @"C:\" + file;
}
```

The good thing about using this approach is that when you browse the folder where you're saving the files, **they will be sorted.**

and then use it in your existing code:

```
bitmap.Save(GenerateFilename(), ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

You can also prepend any text (like `image-` or something) to the filename.

Another option would be append an integer to the end of the filename, like some copy handling programs do.

Answer (score 1):

There is already something for that:  [Path.GetTempFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx)